# geth console not displaying rinkeby eth balance

Tags: ether, rinkeby, balances

I'm running geth 1.10.3 locally by running 'geth --rinkeby'.

I then run geth console with:

'geth --rinkeby attach ipc:\.\pipe\geth.ipc'

eth.coinbase is set to the account I am looking at.

When I run:

eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase);

or

web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), 'ether')

...all that is returned is 0.

I have checked the address on rinkeby.etherscan.io, and it has the expected amount of eth. The latest synced block displayed by 'eth.syncing' is past the transaction block numbers in etherscan. I have imported the account into metamask and see the expected amount of eth.

When I check the address on etherscan.io, it does look like there is an account with 0 ether. Could I somehow be connecting the console to the main network instead of rinkeby?

Comment: Hi there. Is have you completed syncing the chain data?

Comment: eth.syncing returns:

> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 8546004,
  highestBlock: 8546073,
  knownStates: 189089851,
  pulledStates: 189071242,
  startingBlock: 8543939
}

The block number of one of the eth transfer transactions are 8539512 and 8545761.

Comment: Ah, I'll check again after the sync is complete.

Comment: Yes, it had to finish syncing. Eth now shows in geth console.